# Why am I getting this error when I do have a getter in my provider

Tags: flutter, dart

In my provider class I have this code

```
List<Post> get items {
    return [..._items]; //spread operator to copy the list
  }
```

And in my list widget I have this

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final post = Provider.of<Posts>(context);

    return ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
            ProductDetailScreen.routeName,
            arguments: post.id,
          );
        },
```

Can someone tell me why I am getting this error..

The getter 'id' isn't defined for the type 'Posts'.
Try importing the library that defines 'id', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'id'.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there is some kind of confusion here with the Provider. So I can see that you are getting the `Posts` class, is that the one you want to get? And does this class/model/entity contain an attribute `id`.

It feels to me like you are trying to get a `Post` instead of `Posts`. Just let me know if this helps and if not, please clarify what you want to achieve and show the other code of the `Posts`

Comment: thanks..that was it. I needed to change to this..final post = Provider.of<Post>(context);